# Different versions of ubuntu with chroot environment

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, debootstrap

I was trying to setup a chroot environment on older system using debootstrap. I had ubuntu 14.04 and I was wondering what version of ubuntu i can possibly install on it. If I were to  try and run ubuntu 20.04 should there be any risk for the host system? And more generally, how far apart can the versions be - is there any limit at all?

While the problem was solved by simply upgrading the old system (about time) the question remains.

When I tried to set it up i used debootstrap to create chroot folder in something like `/root/${distro}-root`, then I mounted folders as in [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). I then run chroot on that folder. Everything worked as intended. After that though when I rebooted the host system it would not boot up.

Comment: There is no risk. The only thing that possible could not work is some systemd-related things inside the chroot, since it is dependent on certain kernel modules that may, or may not be activated or present.

Comment: That's what I thought too, however when I did it chroot worked great, everything was OK except when trying to reboot the host system it wasn't booting again. It wasn't just once too, I did it 3 times and always with the same effect.

Comment: Huh, I feel like there is information missing. How did you set that up? Did you run debootstrap in /?